# How can i link the whole content element with the header_link

Tags: css, typo3, typoscript

I've a problem, and it seems be so simple as it sounds.

I've on my TYPO3 Site different Page-Layouts. I've defined several frames which will style a content element. so 'til now nothing special. But now I want that my text-pic content element can be wrapped with the link from the picture or even with the link from the headline of the content element. Actually i worked in the frames with css and i had the picture in the back with some text over it. and now should the whole content element be the link from the picture or even from the headline.

This should be only on Content-Elements with specific frames. "That's it" :)

Can anyone help me?

Meanwhile I tried:

```
20.stdWrap.typolink {
    parameter = file:current:link _parent
    if.value = field:section_frame
    if.equals = 200
}
```

But the problem here is that I won't take the current site as a link so it can also be the link in the image data. it should not be the header_link.

I saw that this link is located under:`tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap.typolink`

But how can i set this link dynamically as parameter of my typolink?

Hope anyone can help me, because i saw in the web many peoples asking the same but no one can explain it exactly how it works.

Comment: You have a frames page like this? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp

Comment: Sorry it was a little bit unclear. I've defined several Frames in TCE to adapt to a content-Element as CSS class to style them. That's why i wrote "This should be only on CE with specific frames". my fault. hope it is clearer now.

Comment: What TYPO3 version are you using? Are you rendering your content with css_styled_content or with fluid_styled_content?

Comment: I'm using 6.2.13 I'm rendering my content with css_styled_content. I've tried several things like I extend to my question above.

Comment: Hope you can help me @Daniel

Comment: You cant use "file" and "field" data attributes without ".data".. Try to change your typolink to the following: parameter.data = file:current:link

Answer (score 0):

Like i already said in my comment:
You need to use ".data" on your parameter to link the a field or a file attribute. Also you can not use a if statement inside a typolink because typolink is not stdWrap. You have to use it on the stdWrap before or on the parameter property.

Try the following example:

```
20.stdWrap {
    typolink {
        parameter.data = file:current:link

        #target for internal sites
        target = _parent

        #target for files
        fileTarget = _parent

        #target for external sites
        extTarget = _parent   
    }    

    if {
        value = 200
        equals.field = section_frame
    }

}
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I'll try this. can't wait to try it out. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. But perhaps i put it to the false position. Can you tell me what exactly is bevor "20" so then can i put the whole into the setup.ts file. Then it is on the right place, right? Is it "tt_content.textpic." ?thank you for your help.

Comment: You cant wrap a whole content element with the file:current:link, because you need to be in the FILE Objects to access file:current:link.. Alternatively you can take the link out of "header_link" and wrap the content with before and after.. Let me know, if you need help.